# installing dionysus on windows

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to run [this project](https://github.com/satoru-watanabe-aw/DNNtopology) in GitHub.

Everything seems good until I try to import this library:

**dionysus** by *pip install dionysus*, (in the file *drawDiagram.ipynb*) an error throw:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  

  **× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [73 lines of output]
      C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:771: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dionysus
      copying bindings\python\dionysus\plot.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dionysus
      copying bindings\python\dionysus\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dionysus
      copying bindings\python\dionysus\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dionysus
      running build_ext
      C:\Users\medba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7r1n4bs5\dionysus_9786be67ef684cb09fdd6e6ba56ce711\setup.py:34: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
        cmake_version = LooseVersion(re.search(r'version\s*([\d.]+)', out.decode()).group(1))
      -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (project):
        Generator
      
          NMake Makefiles
      
        does not support platform specification, but platform ..**
```

i'm using windows os.
any help :)

Comment: You may need to ask on their support forum.  It's not clear how much infrastructure has to be present to install this on WIndows.  https://github.com/mrzv/dionysus

Comment: this library is old, i think it's better to find a new alternative. do you know another one?

Comment: "Old" does not mean "bad".  Many projects do exactly what they need to do, and then no more improvements are needed.

Comment: The main problem I face is the lack of documentation and support, so I'm thinking of other alternatives., thank you @TimRoberts for the help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answers your question directly, but it may solve the problem.

The only solution I have been able to find is running it on windows subsystem for linux (WSL). Here are the steps I took:

1. Turn on WSL in settings. This will require a restart.
2. Install ubunto. Can get from microsoft store.
3. Command line: `wsl`
4. Command line: `sudo apt update && upgrade`
5. Command line: `sudo apt install python3 python3-pip ipython3`
6. Command line: `sudo apt-get install cmake`
7. Command line: `sudo apt-get intall libboost-dev-all`
8. Command line: `sudo pip install dionysus`
9. pip install any other packages you need to run code (e.g., numpy, networkx, etc.)
10. Command line: `sudo pip install jupyter`
11. Command line: `run jupyter notebook`